# Menu item not in the middle CSS

Tags: html, css

The menu items are not in the middle and the text are not centralised either. I would like to achieve something like the following. Secondly, the current menu item doesn't turn into the colour specified in the stylesheet.

Not sure which line causes it but here's a bit of the code:

```
#navigation ul li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    line-height: 58px;
    padding: 0 22px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial;
}
```

See JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ahu75/

[image]

Comment: are you expecting like this http://jsfiddle.net/ahu75/4/

Comment: nope, i was wanting something like the above image, and when it's hovered, the entire menu item box gets changed. now I think the position of the menu item (text) seems to be a little off: a little right and down.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LHCGq/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add (margin:0) to #navigation ul.

```
#navigation ul {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    float: left;
    min-height: 58px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a margin at the top and the botom of your ul, set it to 0:

```
#navigation ul {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    float: left;
    min-height: 58px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

For the current item, in the fiddle css current-menu-item is the class for the selected item while current_page_item is used in the html :)

Comment: you have come up with the same answer as Srinu Basava, you can upvote his if you have the same answer instead of posting it again